# Classifying normal closures of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory

**Vague Question:**

1. Let $G$ be a group. Is it possible to classify all groups $N$ such that $G \subseteq N$ and $N$ is the normal closure of $G$?

Presumably if this is ever feasible, it is difficult in general.

**More Pointed Refinements:**

2. Let $G$ be a group. Is it ever the case that there are only a set of possible normal closures $N \supseteq G$ (up to isomorphism)? Is it ever the case that there are a proper class of nonisomorphic normal closures $N \supseteq G$?
3. Are there examples of groups $G$ for which all possible normal closures $N \supseteq G$ can be "classified" in some sense?
4. Are there any general methods for carrying out such a classification for a particular group $G$?

I suppose I'd also be interested in any pointers toward restricted versions of the question, such as classifying normal closures which contain $G$ as a finite-index subgroup.

Comment: Every group embeds in the alternating group of every arbitrary large set (group of even f.g. permutation), which is a simple group. So answer to 2 is no. Answer to 3 is certainly no, the answer can't depend on the group since any two group simultaneously embed into a larger simple group, and classification as in 3 would mean classifying large simple groups. Hence, also no for 4.

Comment: The finite index question is dramatically different (and makes sense even without the normal closure assumption), I'd better comment it if asked separately.

Comment: A tiny remark: If $G$ is a (not necessarily finite) simple group and $G$ embeds in another group $H$, then either $G \lhd H$ or else $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(H/G)$, where $H/G$ denotes the set of right cosets of $G$ in $H$. This is because, in the second case, $\bigcap_{h \in H} h^{-1}Gh$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ contained in $G$, so must be trivial, as $G$ is simple, and this intersection is proper in $G$ if $G$ is not normal in $H$.